# Help with a Minecraft Piece Analysis?

Tags: analysis

[image]

So I did an anlysis for a Minecraft Piece for a video I'm working on. I was wondering if there were any glaring errors?

I called the chords that had arpeggiated the 9th Maj9 chords, but for some that just had them as passing tones I decided it best to analyze those as non chord tones.

The brief modulation at the end, should that be a modulation or just a secondary subdominant moving to a secondary dominant? Also did I notate that modulation correctly? I was pretty sure it was a direct modulation so I went ahead with that and just said it modulated on the scale degree.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m sure some other readers will chip in with a full appraisal of your analysis and/or other points, but I just thought I’d make a comment about sus2 chords: a sus2 chord doesn’t have a third, as the suspended second is a suspension OF the third. Chords with seconds like these are either add9 chords (if there is no 7th) or 9th chords (if there is a 7th). You may benefit from searching this site, or elsewhere online, for further info about suspended chords and how tertian harmony influences chord naming.

Comment: I just went ahead and made some of the changes, fixing the "sus2" chords and calling them 9 chords properly. How does it look now?

Comment: I was wondering if my notation for the ii(9) was correct, since it'sr a minor 7th but a major 9th? Also, is how I did the direct modulation correct, or is that even a direct modulation? Is it just IV/IV going to V/IV?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm a little bit late, but I don't think there is a modulation at all. After he plays G major, he never resolves to D. Instead, he always goes back to A. There is no moment where D feels like the tonal center.

Also, you got a little confused in 15. Bm9 is ii9 in relation to A, not D. Considering the modulation, vi9 would be right.

Having said that, I would:

- Rip out the modulation;
- Change 9, 10, 11, 12, 17 and 21 to VIIb (maj9 or add9);
- Change 13, 14, 18 and 22 to I.